# How to save data received from the Python console on a remote server in Clickhouse?

Tags: python, google-sheets, airflow, clickhouse

How to **save data** from https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/ using gspread (for example, if you have a better method, please tell us) in order to transfer it to the **clickhouse** database (I use dag from airflow to control etl ) ?

Answers in the documentation are not very clear for newbies, are there step-by-step guides?

Just get data in the *console Python* - I can, but here's how to save them, given that you will need to pull the data periodically once a day (intermittency is just the work of airflow - I know how )

I have an assumption that you need to connect to clickhouse, this will be a data stream from a file that generates a Python script on the *airflow* side-once a day, and in the future, sent to Clickhouse over https. Do you have an step-by-step tutorial for that ?

Or what is the best technology to use for this purpose?

Actualy my code looks like this (I think first learn how to get it on the locale, and then wrap it in dag airflow to automate the script launch)

```
    import gspread
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    import pprint
    
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json',scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    
    sheet = client.open('Data base').sheet4
    
    result = sheet.get_all_records()
    print(result)

#in advance I apologize to the elders for the question from a novice
```

Comment: About `what is the best technology to use for this purpose?`, in this case, the languages except for python are also included in your goal?

Comment: We are going to use Airflow for process management - and keep all scripts on Python, so at this case - no

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about the direction of your goal.